# C# LINQ to XML query with duplicate element names that have attributes

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

```
        <Party id="Party_1">
            <PartyTypeCode tc="1">Person</PartyTypeCode>
            <FullName>John Doe</FullName>
            <GovtID>123456789</GovtID>
            <GovtIDTC tc="1">Social Security Number US</GovtIDTC>
            <ResidenceState tc="35">New Jersey</ResidenceState>
            <Person>
                <FirstName>Frank</FirstName>
                <MiddleName>Roberts</MiddleName>
                <LastName>Madison</LastName>                    
                <Prefix>Dr.</Prefix>
                <Suffix>III</Suffix>
                <Gender tc="1">Male</Gender>
                <BirthDate>1974-01-01</BirthDate>
                <Age>35</Age>
                <Citizenship tc="1">United States of America</Citizenship>
            </Person>
            <Address>
                <AddressTypeCode tc="26">Bill Mailing</AddressTypeCode>
                <Line1>2400 Meadow Lane</Line1>
                <Line2></Line2>
                <Line3></Line3>
                <Line4></Line4>
                <City>Somerset</City>
                <AddressStateTC tc="35">New Jersey</AddressStateTC>
                <Zip>07457</Zip>
                <AddressCountryTC tc="1">United States of America</AddressCountryTC>
            </Address>
        </Party>
        <!-- ***********************  -->
        <!--  Insured Information     -->
        <!-- ***********************  -->
        <Party id="Party_2">
            <PartyTypeCode tc="1">Person</PartyTypeCode>
            <FullName>Dollie Robert Madison</FullName>
            <GovtID>123956239</GovtID>
            <GovtIDTC tc="1">Social Security Number US</GovtIDTC>
            <Person>
                <FirstName>Dollie</FirstName>
                <MiddleName>R</MiddleName>
                <LastName>Madison</LastName>
                <Suffix>III</Suffix>
                <Gender tc="2">Female</Gender>
                <BirthDate>1996-10-12</BirthDate>
                <Citizenship tc="1">United States of America</Citizenship>
            </Person>
            <!-- Insured Address -->
            <Address>
                <AddressTypeCode tc="26">Bill Mailing</AddressTypeCode>
                <Line1>2400 Meadow Lane</Line1>
                <City>Somerset</City>
                <AddressStateTC tc="35">New Jersey</AddressStateTC>
                <Zip>07457</Zip>
                <AddressCountryTC tc="1">United States of America</AddressCountryTC>
            </Address>
            <Risk>
                <!-- Disability Begin Effective Date -->
                <DisabilityEffectiveStartDate>2006-01-01</DisabilityEffectiveStartDate>
                <!-- Disability End Effective Date -->
                <DisabilityEffectiveStopDate>2008-01-01</DisabilityEffectiveStopDate>
            </Risk>
        </Party>
        <!-- *******************************  -->
        <!--  Company Information     -->
        <!-- ******************************  -->
        <Party id="Party_3">
            <PartyTypeCode tc="2">Organization</PartyTypeCode>
            <Organization>
                <DTCCMemberCode>1234</DTCCMemberCode>
            </Organization>
            <Carrier>
                <CarrierCode>105</CarrierCode>
            </Carrier>
        </Party>
```

Here is my code which doesn't work because party 3 doesn't contain FullName, I know that partyelements contains 3 parties if I only return the name attribute. Is there a way to loop through each tag seperate?

```
        var partyElements = from party in xmlDoc.Descendants("Party")
           select new
           {
               Name = party.Attribute("id").Value,
               PartyTypeCode = party.Element("PartyTypeCode").Value,
               FullName = party.Element("FullName").Value,
               GovtID = party.Element("GovtID").Value,
           };
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something along these lines? (more of an idea/suggestion than an implementation, because I don't know your object model)

```
var parties = xmlDoc.Descendants("Party");
foreach(var party in parties)
{
    int partyTypeCode = party.Element("PartyTypeCode").Value;
    if(partyTypeCode == 1)
    {
        var person = personFactory.Build(party);
        // do something
    }
    else if(partyTypeCode == 2)
    {
        var organization = companyFactory.Build(party);
        // do something
    }
}
```

In a perfectly polymorphic world, you'd just have a `PartyFactory` and no `if` or `switch` statements, but a person party and a company party are quite different.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid a NullReferenceException when accessing the `FullName` element you can cast it to a string without calling `Value` on the element. If it doesn't exist null will be returned, otherwise the value will be returned. You can then check for null while iterating over the results.

Change: `FullName = party.Element("FullName").Value,`

To: `FullName = (string)party.Element("FullName"),`

The updated query would be:

```
var partyElements = from party in xmlDoc.Descendants("Party")
    select new
    {
        Name = party.Attribute("id").Value,
        PartyTypeCode = party.Element("PartyTypeCode").Value,
        FullName = (string)party.Element("FullName"),
        GovtID = party.Element("GovtID").Value,
    };
```

You can do the same thing for all elements that may or may not exist for certain items.

Answer (score 0):

I feel Ahmed's solution is the way to go. But here is the hack I came up with. If 'FullName' is the only distinguishing Element between two different types of party nodes then I guess the following may work:

```
var validParty = xElement.Descendants("Party")
                            .Elements().Where(x => x.Name == "FullName")
                            .Ancestors("Party")
                            .Elements().Where(x => x.Name == "PartyTypeCode")
                            .Ancestors("Party");


 var partyElements = from party in validParty 
            select new
            {
                Name = party.Attribute("id").Value,
                PartyTypeCode = party.Element("PartyTypeCode").Value,
                FullName = party.Element("FullName").Value,
                GovtID = party.Element("GovtID").Value,
            };
```

You may add additional distinguishing nodes if any like the "PartyTypeCode". I am not sure about the performance aspect of this.